# PHP Latitude Longitude to Address

Tags: php, geolocation, location, latitude-longitude

I have a form on my website where a user enters an address of a place. When they submit the form, I convert this location into latitude/longitude and store this in a MySQL Database. I am using Google's Geocode service for this conversion. The problem is that I can't find either a class or a service to convert that latitude/longitude back to an address and as far as I know, Google's Geocode service is a unidirectional conversion. I realize I could store the physical address in the database, but over time this is wasted space when it could be stored in a simpler format. Does anybody know of either a class/service to convert from latitude/longitude to a address or if I am wrong and I can use Google's geocode system? I have looked for the answer for the past few days but couldn't find anything. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for Google's (or anyone else's) [*reverse geocoding* service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

Comment: Ok awesome, this works perfect. I've been trying to find this for the last few days, Thanks!

Comment: just be aware of googles TOS (Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 12):

Conversion of geo-coordinates into address is known as Reverse Geocoding. In this script we are using Google map API because it’s free, fast and no API key required.

Rate Limit of Google reveres Geocoding is 2500 API calls per IP per day.

**PHP function for Reveres Geocoding**

```
<?
  function getaddress($lat,$lng)
  {
     $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
     $json = @file_get_contents($url);
     $data=json_decode($json);
     $status = $data->status;
     if($status=="OK")
     {
       return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
     }
     else
     {
       return false;
     }
  }
?>
```

Pass latitude and longitude in getaddress() function. It will return address string on success otherwise return boolean false.

**Example**

```
<?php
  $lat= 26.754347; //latitude
  $lng= 81.001640; //longitude
  $address= getaddress($lat,$lng);
  if($address)
  {
    echo $address;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not found";
  }
?>
```

Comment: The URL should be https.  Google now requires requests to this API must be over SSL.  Otherwise you get a 'REQUEST_DENIED' error.

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php

/* 
* Given longitude and latitude in North America, return the address using The Google Geocoding API V3
*
*/

function Get_Address_From_Google_Maps($lat, $lon) {

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$lon&sensor=false";

// Make the HTTP request
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
// Parse the json response
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);

// If the json data is invalid, return empty array
if (!check_status($jsondata))   return array();

$address = array(
    'country' => google_getCountry($jsondata),
    'province' => google_getProvince($jsondata),
    'city' => google_getCity($jsondata),
    'street' => google_getStreet($jsondata),
    'postal_code' => google_getPostalCode($jsondata),
    'country_code' => google_getCountryCode($jsondata),
    'formatted_address' => google_getAddress($jsondata),
);

return $address;
}

/* 
* Check if the json data from Google Geo is valid 
*/

function check_status($jsondata) {
    if ($jsondata["status"] == "OK") return true;
    return false;
}

/*
* Given Google Geocode json, return the value in the specified element of the array
*/

function google_getCountry($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("country", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"]);
}
function google_getProvince($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("administrative_area_level_1", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"], true);
}
function google_getCity($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("locality", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"]);
}
function google_getStreet($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("street_number", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"]) . ' ' . Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("route", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"]);
}
function google_getPostalCode($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("postal_code", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"]);
}
function google_getCountryCode($jsondata) {
    return Find_Long_Name_Given_Type("country", $jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"], true);
}
function google_getAddress($jsondata) {
    return $jsondata["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
}

/*
* Searching in Google Geo json, return the long name given the type. 
* (If short_name is true, return short name)
*/

function Find_Long_Name_Given_Type($type, $array, $short_name = false) {
    foreach( $array as $value) {
        if (in_array($type, $value["types"])) {
            if ($short_name)    
                return $value["short_name"];
            return $value["long_name"];
        }
    }
}

/*
*  Print an array
*/

function d($a) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($a);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: I am using the above code in PHP and usually it works very well - however sometimes Get_Address_From_Google_Maps($lat, $lon) returns null for $address. Have you ever seen that issue and any suggestions? It is very intermittent but does happen. The lat, lon is valid and previously returned a valid address but on a second call, or third call, or nth call for same lat, lon will return a null for address? Any thoughts on why?

Comment: The URL should be https.  Google now requires requests to this API must be over SSL.  Otherwise you get a 'REQUEST_DENIED' error.

Answer (score 2):

Geolocation  PHP convert Latitude Longitude to Address.
First you need to get the api key for google map api that you find using below link:

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#ReverseGeocoding](https://www.lelocode.com/posts/geolocation-php-latitude-longitude-to-address---lelocode)

After put the below function into your helper class and call that function anywhere you want simple passing lat and long. After passing lat long they return address regarding lat long values. That whole process called Reverse Geocoding.

```
/**
 * find address using lat long
 */
public static function geolocationaddress($lat, $long)
{
    $geocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$lat,$long&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCJyDp4TLGUigRfo4YN46dXcWOPRqLD0gQ";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $geocode);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $output = json_decode($response);
    $dataarray = get_object_vars($output);
    if ($dataarray['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS' && $dataarray['status'] != 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
        if (isset($dataarray['results'][0]->formatted_address)) {

            $address = $dataarray['results'][0]->formatted_address;

        } else {
            $address = 'Not Found';

        }
    } else {
        $address = 'Not Found';
    }

    return $address;
}
```

For more details checkout below link:
[Geolocation PHP Latitude Longitude to Address - Lelocode](https://www.lelocode.com/posts/geolocation-php-latitude-longitude-to-address---lelocode)